# Create a new column that is filled with value from other table if it is found between range of 2 other columns in the other table

Tags: r, tidyverse

Suppose I have the first data frame that looks like this (dfA)

```
CHR  POS  
1    100    
1    200    
2    100
2    200
```

And I have another data frame that looks like this (dfB)

```
CHR  START  STOP  VALUE   
1    0      150   1000
1    200    300   2000
2    0      300   3000
```

What I want to have is a new **column** in dfA if `dfA$POS` values are found within the range of `dfB$START` and `dfB$STOP`. Additionally, the first column must match with each other (dfA and dfB both have the same first column CHR).

If found, the row in the new column in dfA will be filled with the value in `dfB$VALUE`.

The result should look like this

```
CHR  POS  VALUE
1    100  1000
1    200  2000
2    100  3000
2    200  3000
```

How would I go about doing this? Thanks for the help!

Comment: You can also have a look at `data.table`'s non-equi joins. Or `sqldf` package. There are several examples on SO already.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `between` to determine if values fall in a specified range.

```
library(dplyr)

dfA %>%
  left_join(dfB) %>%
  rowwise() %>% 
  filter(between(POS, START, STOP)) %>%
  select(-c(START, STOP)) %>%
  ungroup()

# # A tibble: 4 x 3
#     CHR   POS VALUE
#   <int> <int> <int>
# 1     1   100  1000
# 2     1   200  2000
# 3     2   100  3000
# 4     2   200  3000
```